# How to disable OTA update of some specific apps?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ota-update

My android device is 4.4.2 with no root access.

I would like to disable OTA updates of some specific apps like facebook and other apps.

Can it be possible?

Please let me know, how to do this?

Regards

InTech

Comment: Do you mean application updates via Google Playstore?

Comment: In some cases, we see application updates on Play Store. And in some cases we see frequent notification for application updates on an application screen. If I would be able to disable both for some applications, it will be really great for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted, you can use Titanium Backup and Freeze the system app named "Software Update MUC". This prevents the phone from self checking for updates and the notifications will stop.